# Pandas merging columns by reverse compliment string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-manipulation

So I am stuck on how to approach a data manipulation technique in pandas. I have an example dataframe below with a sum of 25 counts in each row. 
I would like to merge column names by the reverse compliment sequence.

```
   AA CC GG AT TT

    4  7  0  9  5
    3  8  5  5  2
    8  6  2  8  1
```

The columns "AA" and "TT" are reverse compliments of each other as are "CC" and "GG"

```
   AA/TT CC/GG AT 

    9     7     9
    5     13    5
    9     8     8
```

How can I match the reverse compliment of a column name and merge it with the name of another column.

**Note: I already have a function to find the reverse compliment of a string**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just creating a new frame using `pd.concat`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df[['AA', 'TT']].sum(1).rename('AA/TT'),
                    df[['CC', 'GG']].sum(1).rename('CC/GG'),
                    df['AT']], axis=1)

>>> new_df
   AA/TT  CC/GG  AT
0      9      7   9
1      5     13   5
2      9      8   8
```

More generally, you could do it in a list comprehension. Given the reverse compliments:

```
reverse_compliments = [['AA','TT'], ['CC','GG']]
```

Find those values in your original dataframe columns that are not in reverse compliments (There might be a better way here, but this works):

```
reverse_compliments.append(df.columns.difference(
    pd.np.array(reverse_compliments)
    .flatten()))
```

And use `pd.concat` with a list comprehension:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df[x].sum(1).rename('/'.join(x)) for x in reverse_compliments],
                   axis=1)

>>> new_df
   AA/TT  CC/GG  AT
0      9      7   9
1      5     13   5
2      9      8   8
```

Comment: Hi @sacul, That works for this demo example and I think it is putting me on the right direction. Is there a more pythonic way to call the columns than individually typing each reverse compliment? (i.e. if I have two lists of column name and reverse compliment) Thank you very much though. I have tinkering to do!

Comment: Thank you @sacul. This works for what I need. There is some edge cases (such as when the reverse compliment is not in the original dataframe). You are awesome and have been extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Hope you figure out your edge cases! And I'm sure there is a better way to get the non-included columns, but I'm glad this pointed you in a direction you can work with.